# How to pass EditText value to two different activities with one button?

Tags: java, android-studio

So I want to pass EditText value to two different activities using one button(**submit** button). Logically I did everything correctly but it doesn't work and I don't know why. I think it doesn't work that way. Here's my **FIRST** activity code:

```
public class TwoTeam extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText first_name, second_name;
    String name_first, name_second;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two_team);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.second_name);

    }

    public void submit_button(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TwoTeam.this, Begin.class);{
            name_first = first_name.getText().toString();
            name_second = second_name.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("name1", name_first);
            intent.putExtra("name2", name_second);
            intent.putExtra("turn1", name_first + "'s Turn");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        Intent in = new Intent(TwoTeam.this, Begindup.class);{
            name_first = first_name.getText().toString();
            name_second = second_name.getText().toString();
            in.putExtra("name1dup", name_first);
            in.putExtra("name2dup", name_second);
            in.putExtra("turn2", name_second + "'s Turn");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my **Second** activity code:

```
public class Begin extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView first_name, second_name, first_turn, words;
    String name_first, name_second, turn_first;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.name_first);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.name_second);
        first_turn = findViewById(R.id.first_turn);

        name_first = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1");
        first_name.setText(name_first);

        name_second = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name2");
        second_name.setText(name_second);

        turn_first = getIntent().getExtras().getString("turn1");
        first_turn.setText(turn_first);
    }
}
```

And here's my **THIRD** activity code:

```
public class Begindup extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView first_name, second_name, second_turn, words;
    String name_first, name_second, turn_second;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begindup);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.name_first);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.name_second);
        second_turn = findViewById(R.id.second_turn);

        name_first = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1dup");
        first_name.setText(name_first);

        name_second = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name2dup");
        second_name.setText(name_second);

        turn_second = getIntent().getExtras().getString("turn2");
        second_turn.setText(turn_second);
    }
}
```

Error output is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

And sometimes this too:

```
Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
```

Comment: Does moving `name_first = first_name.getText().toString(); name_second = second_name.getText().toString();`before your intent-creation solve your problem?

Comment: Error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: for an already running application, the hit will come to override function onNewIntent(Intent intent). Have u tried accessing from it.  check for getIntent() == null so that u can avoid crash and tried accessing from onNewIntent

Comment: The code information may be lacking. When does the NPE happen? Inside Begin.class I presume, right?

You may also try to directly use `getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");` rather than `getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1");`

Answer (score 0):

The code information may be lacking. I presume the NPE happens inside `Begin.class`, right?

You may try to directly use `getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");` rather than `getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1");`. This way your code no longer need to retrieve the Bundle object(that may possibly be null) but instead directly retrieves the String extra you need.